# Getting the XML response from DispatcherServlet which is just cut off and no error is logged

Tags: spring, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a project with Spring (config is below):

```
<import resource="classpath:payment-impl-context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:abs-payment-consumer-context.xml"/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres"/>

<security:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" create-session="stateless">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api2/xml/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="webServiceAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.openpayment.web.service"/>

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>payment-messages</value>
            <value>web-service-messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and it calls for the controller with

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/xml;charset=cp1251", produces = "application/xml;charset=cp1251")
```

and when seializing the data

```
invokeAndHandle:117, ServletInvocableHandlerMethod (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation)
invokeHandlerMethod:854, RequestMappingHandlerAdapter (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation)
handleInternal:765, RequestMappingHandlerAdapter (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation)
handle:85, AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method)
doDispatch:967, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doDispatch:41, LoggableDispatcherServlet (com.openpayment.web.service.init)
doService:901, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processRequest:970, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doPost:872, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:647, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
service:846, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:728, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
internalDoFilter:305, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:210, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:51, WsFilter (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server)
internalDoFilter:243, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:210, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:317, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
invoke:127, FilterSecurityInterceptor (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept)
doFilter:91, FilterSecurityInterceptor (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:114, ExceptionTranslationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.access)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:111, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:170, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (org.springframework.security.web.servletapi)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:158, BasicAuthenticationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www)
doFilter:107, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:66, HeaderWriterFilter (org.springframework.security.web.header)
doFilter:107, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:56, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async)
doFilter:107, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:105, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:214, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:177, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
invokeDelegate:347, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:263, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:243, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:210, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:222, StandardWrapperValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:123, StandardContextValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:502, AuthenticatorBase (org.apache.catalina.authenticator)
invoke:171, StandardHostValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:100, ErrorReportValve (org.apache.catalina.valves)
invoke:953, AccessLogValve (org.apache.catalina.valves)
invoke:118, StandardEngineValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
service:408, CoyoteAdapter (org.apache.catalina.connector)
process:1041, AbstractHttp11Processor (org.apache.coyote.http11)
process:603, AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler (org.apache.coyote)
run:310, JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor (org.apache.tomcat.util.net)
runWorker:1128, ThreadPoolExecutor (java.util.concurrent)
run:628, ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker (java.util.concurrent)
run:834, Thread (java.lang)
```

I was getting trace message, that I have fount only under debug mode.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName (through reference chain: com.openpayment.external.pay24.model.GetUIProvidersResponse["providers"]->com.openpayment.external.pay24.model.GetUIProvidersResponse$Providers["getUIProviders"]->com.openpayment.external.pay24.model.GetUIProvidersResponse$GetUIProviders["provider"]->java.util.ArrayList[53]->com.openpayment.external.pay24.model.GetUIProvidersResponse$Provider["field"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.openpayment.external.pay24.model.GetUIProvidersResponse$Field["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

and as the result the output is just broken XML, which is correct till the failure place and then is just interrupted

Why I'm not getting 500 Server error then? But just 200 and XML data cut off?

Comment: Note: HTTP response status and headers are irreversible when they've already been flushed/sent/written from the server to the client. Looks like the exception took place *after* that. Try bumping the response buffer size to avoid the status and headers being sent "too early". Or better yet try completing the exception-sensitive business logic before writing to response at all.

Comment: @BalusC I was surprized that Sprng's magic doesn't do it for me :)